# Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Optional<Swift.AnyObject>' (0x7f9d44715db0) to 'NSArray' (0x60000004f4f8)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to check `responseObject != nil` But It returns always true.

I don't know *(How to check `nil` value for `ANY?`)*

**Here is my code**:

```
success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation?,responseObject: Any?) in
                print("view service reponse: \(String(describing: responseObject))")
                print("view service reponse: \(responseObject!)")                
                if responseObject != nil
                {
                    let jsonObjects : NSArray = responseObject as! NSArray
                    print("All data1 : \(String(describing: jsonObjects))")

                    for dataDict : Any in jsonObjects {
```

**Crash Issue** :

[image]

**In Log Message:**

> view service reponse: Optional(nil)
>
> view service reponse: nil
>
> Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Optional' (0x7f9d44715db0) to 'NSArray' (0x60000004f4f8).
>   (lldb)

I tried below code also,

```
if let jsonOject = responseObject as? NSArray {
    // mean your responce is array type
}
else{
    // oterwise your responce in not array
}
```

But still I got a crash...

Comment: kindly post `responseObject `

Comment: responseObject is surely hungry for something else. You getting crash because type casting is wrong. You need to cast it to required type.

Comment: responseObject is  NSDictionary

Comment: Here I updated my post @RAJAMOHAN-S

Comment: try this :                     let jsonObjects  = responseObject as! [Any] // if Array .... let jsonObjects  = responseObject as! [String : AnyObject]// if dictionary

Comment: If `responseObject != nil` succeeds then you need to dereference `responseObject`. It contains an optional in an optional. Normally an optional is `.some<T>` or `.none`. Your type contains `.some<.none>`. And **do not use `NSArray` / `NSDictionary` in Swift**. Use the native types. And **do not annotate types the compiler can infer**

Comment: As @vadian said responseObject has an optional inside an optional. You can try "responseObject.response" which actually holds the data. Also whenever your are expecting an optional prefer using "guard" or unwrap it. Prefer using "Dictionary" whenever you are expecting json(its always better this way).

Comment: I tried above all of this method. But Its still return same crash or compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Array instead of NSArray.
While migrating to Swift from Objective C people tend to use NSArray and NSDictionary.